# Features bruteforcing in Naive Bayes

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian-networks

I have a dataset of classified text strings.

I'm currently using a simple vocabulary (occurrences) as unique feature. Would it be possible to have a learning function to generate random regexp on the data to extract features and see if we get better results instead of having to try to create features by myself (exemple: does this sentence contain a ".")?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes - you can do anything.

A bit longer one is that you can generate random regexes, however:

- you will need to find our own way of constructing them, and it will be a strong bias (a prior over features) which might (or might not) lead to reasonable models
- Consider changing classifier to something more advanced that NB if results are bad instead, this will be better justified and easier to achieve - think about some linear models
- for NLP there are numerours methods of representing your data which might be better, start with things like TfIDF, and if it fails you can look for modern words embedding (representation learning)